# Broken Image link while uploading canvas base64 image to parse.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

My Application is only html and javascript. Below is my code snippet for saving the base64 imgData on parse.com

```
var parseFile = new Parse.File("mypic.jpeg", {base64:imgData});
                parseFile.save().then(function(data) {
                    console.log("Got it!");
                    console.log("Ok");
                    console.dir(data);

                }, function(error) {
                    console.log("Error");
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

My Doubt is how to get the image source after saving it.

I'm getting image url `console.log(data._url)` but the url is broken.

Can you help to get rid of this problem. I want to get that saved image url. correct me Where I'm wrong.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

got solution..

Issue with base64 image not with above code snippet.
Thank you @Ivan

**Edit:**
The issue is with valid base64 image data.
Previously i was not sending valid base64 image(imgData) to parse.com.
Here my `imgData` is `canvas.todataURL()` data, i was directly sending this image to

```
var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
var parseFile = new Parse.File("mypic.jpeg", {base64:imgData});
```

After I have done below changes

```
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
    var imgData= dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "");
    var parseFile = new Parse.File("mypic.jpeg", {base64:imgData});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that you have to user parseFile.url() into the save's promise function.

```
var parseFile = new Parse.File("mypic.jpeg", {base64:imgData});

parseFile.save().then(function(data) {
        console.log("Got it!");
        console.log("Ok");
        console.dir(data);  
        console.log(parseFile.url());
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```